# update code from github

Tags: github

I have commit code from my desktop computer and now I am in another city and want to update my code in my laptop. What is the command to update a code. I was using svn and it is very easy to update a code like right click on svn local repo and click update but in github I don't know the proper command.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git pull
```

This is the equivalent of svn checkout, not to be confused with git checkout. Type

```
git help
```

to get a list of git commands and an explanation in the shell.

Comment: +1. There’s also a very nice Git tutorial available [directly on GitHub](http://help.github.com/).

Comment: git pull by itself does it on the current branch so if you're on master then it should pull from master etc....